# How can this Infinite series be proven?

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

Recently i read that ( i cannot remember where though)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)!!} = \sqrt{e} $$

Wolfram also confirms this , but I have been looking everywhere to find a proof and i cannot. Could anybody provide one or direct me to a site that provides one?

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!!

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for duplicate.

Comment: Hint: $k!!=2^k k!$